# Why does this not work

Tags: java, variables, double

```
static final double HotDogcp  = MyConstants.HotDog[0]-(MyConstants.HotDog[0] * MyConstants.mu);
static final double [] HotDog = {18, 8, 10, 0};
static double mu =0.25;
```

why does HotDogcp  not equal 13.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static variables are initialized in the order in which they are declared.

In your case, the `mu` variable is still 0 (default value for doubles) when you initialize `HotDogcp`, so `HotDogcp` is intialized to `MyConstants.HotDog[0]`.

If you declare `static double mu =0.25;` before the first line, it would probably do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java is not a mathematical equation solver. Hence the order of statements matters.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are not initialized yet. Put that calculation under the mu pls.

Put initializations inside the constructor. Declarations outside.